# Missing `pino-pretty` module: `pino-pretty` must be installed separately

Tags: node.js, docker, adonis.js, adonisjs-ace

I'm using a adonis js project version 5 and node js version 14 and docker version 20 when i build the application things goes normallly but when i create a docker image and run a container docker i got this error any help please thank you
node server.js

Error: Missing `pino-pretty` module: `pino-pretty` must be installed separately

```
at getPrettyStream (/app/node_modules/pino/lib/tools.js:188:13)

at normalizeArgs (/app/node_modules/pino/lib/tools.js:352:16)

at pino (/app/node_modules/pino/pino.js:78:28)

at getPino (/app/node_modules/@adonisjs/logger/build/src/getPino.js:38:99)

at new Logger (/app/node_modules/@adonisjs/logger/build/src/Logger.js:49:55)

at Application.setupLogger (/app/node_modules/@adonisjs/application/build/src/Application.js:320:23)

at Application.setup (/app/node_modules/@adonisjs/application/build/src/Application.js:513:14)

at HttpServer.wire (/app/node_modules/@adonisjs/core/build/src/Ignitor/HttpServer/index.js:48:32)

at HttpServer.start (/app/node_modules/@adonisjs/core/build/src/Ignitor/HttpServer/index.js:146:24)

at Object.<anonymous> (/server.ts:21:4)
```

Done in 0.68s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've fixed this by moving the `pino-pretty` package from `devDependencies` to production `dependencies`

Comment: Thank you for  your answer ,it may help other people

Answer (score 1):

you have to build app with **production env**

`NODE_ENV=production`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).